# NOTEPAD++ REGEX - I can't get what's in between two strings, I don't get it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm so close to understanding regex. I'm a bit stumped, I thought i understood lazy and greedy.

Here is my current regex: `<g_n><!\[CDATA\[([^]]+)(?=]]><\/g_n>)`

My current regex makes:

```
<g_n><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxx]]></g_n>
```

match to:

```
   <g_n><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxx
```

But I want to make it match like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Good idea! But what language do you use?

Comment: notepad++ no language

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
<g_n><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)]]></g_n>
```

then if you want to replace it use

```
\1
```

in the replacement box

Your matching the whole string, the brackets around the .*? match all of that and put it in the \1 variable

So the match will be all of the string with \1 referring to what you want

To change the xxxxx

Regex :

```
(<g_n><![CDATA[)(?:.*?)(]]></g_n>)
```

Replacement

```
\1WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE TO\2
```

Comment: see i want it to find xxxxxxxxxx anywhere in the text so i can replace xxxxxxxxxx with whatever i want. xxxxxxxxxx is dynamic. i want it to match xxxxxxxxxx only

Comment: ok then (<g_n><!\[CDATA\[)(?:.*?)(\]\]></g_n>)  as the regex and    \1WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE TO\2   as the replacement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add escape slashes to the two closing square brackets, as they are literals from the string you're parsing.

```
<g_n><!\[CDATA\[.*+?\]\]><\/g_n>
                    ^ ^
```

Any square brackets not being escaped by backslashes will be treated as regex operational brackets, which in this case won't catch the input string.

EDIT, I think the +? is redundant.

```
\[.*\]\]> ...
```

should suffice, since .* means any character, any amount of times.

Comment: it still won't match the xxxxxxxxxx unfortunately

Comment: closing square brackets don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with notepad++ 6.3.2:

```
find: (<g_n><!\[CDATA\[)([^]]+)(?=]]></g_n>)
replace: $1WhatYouWant
```

You can replace `+` by `*` in the pattern to match void CDATA:

```
<g_n><![CDATA[]]></g_n>
```

Comment: this is so close, for some reason it's selecting: <g_n><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I know, it's normal. You can't use a lookbehind with notepad++, you must match the beginning too and paste it (with $1)

Comment: wait n/m ... damn this is hard.. i'm so close because of [^] method you use

Comment: @Nell: `[^]]` means all characters that is not a `]`